# Image rotation error in front and rear device camera photo capture intent

Tags: android, image, camera, rotation

HI i have used the following device camera intent to capture and save the image in device storage:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE,lastChar);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        // Start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Everthing is just working fine , camera capturing the image ,saving it into the storage properly, but when i am trying to view the image by fetching image uri from storage and displaying it in the imageview.
Image angle changing all the time.
for Rear camera captured image rotation angle is 90 degree and for front camera capture image rotation angle is 270 degree.

i have added 90 degree rotation to all images , that resolving the rear camra problem , but front camera captured image still have the 180 degree rotation .

thanks in advance , please help me sorting out this issue

Answer (score 3):

Some cameras will actually store JPEG images in the proper rotation; others will set an EXIF header asking the image viewer to rotate the image. `ImageView` does not honor EXIF headers in JPEG files. You will need to use `ExifInterface` (or similar techniques) to see if there is an EXIF orientation header and adjust your image to suit.

Answer (score 1):

i have used the below code to check orientation and changed my imageview rotation to that angle

```
ExifInterface exif;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);

            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                    ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            if (orientation == 6) {
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 3) {
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            } else if (orientation == 8) {
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
            }
```