# Android. Mashmallow. Camera preview always in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-layout, camera

Im using Android Studio. When I execute the code to take a picture, the preview always appears in landscape mode, but the image saves in portrait.
How do I get the preview to show in portrait mode as well?

```
package com.example.scanbarcode.scanbarcode;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class TakePhotoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button takePictureButton;
    private Button nextButton;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri file;
    private String FILE_NAME = "filename";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_photo);

        takePictureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_image);
        nextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_next);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        nextButton.setEnabled(false);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            takePictureButton.setEnabled(false);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                takePictureButton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void takePicture(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        file = Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageView.setImageURI(file);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                intent1.putExtra(FILE_NAME, file.getPath());
                if ((file != null)&&(file.getPath().length() != 0)){
                    nextButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent1);
            }
        }
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile(){
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "CameraDemo");

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()){
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }

    public void nextOnClick(View view){
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

And the layout .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:id="@+id/activity_take_photo"
tools:context="com.example.scanbarcode.scanbarcode.TakePhotoActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:onClick="takePicture"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageview"
    android:text="Take a picture!"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_next"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Next"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageview"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_image"
    android:onClick="nextOnClick"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40159431/115145 https://stackoverflow.com/a/30596702/115145

Comment: Im not having a problem with the images saved at the wrong angle. The PREVIEW is incorrect

Comment: What preview are you referring to? If you are referring to a preview shown in the camera app, contact the developers of the camera app and ask them to fix their bug.

Comment: ... did you actually read through the code?

Comment: Yes, I did. You take a picture with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, which invokes some camera app that the user chooses. You then display the image in an `ImageView`. If by "preview", you mean the `ImageView`, then the links in my first comment are relevant, as `ImageView` ignores EXIF headers. If by "preview", you mean the preview shown in the camera app, that is the camera app's problem, not yours. If by "preview" you mean something else, it is your job to explain **in detail** what you mean by preview.

Comment: Well the camera app I guess would be the "standard" app that comes with marshmallow.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "standard" camera app. Manufacturers routinely ship their own.

Regardless, you have no means of controlling the internal behavior of any camera app with respect to its preview, at least through the standard `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` protocol. It is possible that some camera apps expose their own API, and it is possible that such an API would allow some control over the preview.

So, if you have a reproducible problem with a camera app's preview, identify the developer of the camera app, and try to file a bug report with them.

Comment: Ah.. ok. I follow now what you are saying. Im using an android emulator . Genymotion. Ok. So as long as you think its a bug on the emulator and should work on a real device..

Comment: @Eminem: Well, particularly for the camera, I only ever test on real devices. The closer you get to real hardware, the less I trust an emulator. In this case, see if there is a known Genymotion issue. I am somewhat surprised that they would have different orientations for preview versus the picture, since they do not have any sensors to work with, but I don't use Genymotion.